# Apple guidelines for back button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Are there any guidelines for the position of the back button?

I always see the back button at the top-left part of the screen, but I don't know the exact position I should place it.

Answer (score 4):

It is specified in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/) that there is a default back button positioned in the top left. In full, it reads:

> A navigation bar appears at the top of an app screen, below the status bar, and enables navigation through a series of hierarchical app screens. When a new screen is displayed, a back button, often labeled with the title of the previous screen, appears on the left side of the bar. Sometimes, the right side of a navigation bar contains a control, such as an Edit or a Done button…

More information can be found in the API documentation on the [UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar).

Comment: I more question... when I build the app in the iPhone, the button is automatic spawned or I must implement it?

Comment: @daniel Coding questions should be asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: this is not a coding question, I'm just asking if I need to implement it or not, it's an apple guideline issue

Comment: @caorongjin im not using navigation bar. This guideline is for navigation bar

Comment: @Daniel you'll need to be more specific in the OP  then, because the navigation bar is the standard place for the back button and the guidelines are explained as such.

Comment: And I agree with @patrix, that this is beginning to look more like a coding question.

Comment: @daniel Comments should not be used for follow-up questions, we usually ask people to create a new question in such situations. Looking at the direction your question is heading I wouldn't be surprised if other users would recommend closure (or migration to StackOverflow). Even if not, you'll get better answers on coding-related matters on SO than here (because AD mainly focuses on end-user stuff).